# alias_method': undefined method `current_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forestadmin

Hi i tried to implement forest_admin gem in rails 5 application

When i generate install with this command

```
rails g forest_liana:install <ENVIRONMENT SECRET>
```

The logs are alias_method': undefined method `current_user' for class`ApplicationController' (NameError)

My aplication Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :session_expirada, unless: :devise_controller?
  before_action :set_attr_to_current_user, unless: :devise_controller?
  layout :layout_by_resource
  alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user 
  include RedirectFromEmail
  # Pundi Authorization filtros
  include Pundit

  #after_action :verify_authorized, unless: :devise_controller? ,  #except: :index
  #to catch message error Pundit
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

end
```

What happend?

Comment: Your controller doesn't have method `current_user`. Did it before?

Comment: Yes i put it before but not work

Comment: what do you mean "but not work"?  How did you attempt to define it?  What was the desired behavior and what was the behavior that you experienced?

Comment: Looks like you don't have devise set up.

Comment: I add method current_user but i get the error  `alias_method': undefined method `current_user' for class `ApplicationController' in console. I use devise

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to alias the method ":devise_current_user" to ":current_user".  IN your controller current_user is not defined.  If you define current_user in your controller(see below) then you will not get this error.

```
def current_user
  #logic to get a handle on current user goes here
end
```

Comment: When i run rails g forest_liana:install <ENVIRONMENT SECRET> this add alias_method, I tried add def current_user but not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove alias and just use regular devise `current_user` which is included by default